# resize a large image that does not fit into memory

Tags: python, opencv, gdal

I have a large GeoTiff (let`s say 200,000 by 200,000 pixels) that I need to resize using, for example, opencv or gdal.
The problem I am facing is that I cannot load the entire image into memory, so something like:

```
data_out = cv2.resize(data_in, dsize=dsize, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

is not doable. I thought to tile (or read) the large image into several smaller images (with their own geo-information) so that I can resized each of them individually and then mosaic them back together.
However, this approach seems to suffer at the edges, creating discontinuities across the mosaiced output.

Is there any way I can resize the large image without loading the whole data into memory?

Comment: Yes, you have to avoid loading the whole data into memory. You should find an API which allows for a selective or chunk-based loading of the image from the file. Recommending one isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow, so I would suggest googling for one.

Comment: Make the tiles ovarlap, discard the overlapping parts when putting them together.

Comment: To my knowledge, all of the available [interpolation algorithms](http://tanbakuchi.com/posts/comparison-of-openv-interpolation-algorithms/) use information from some neighbourhood around the pixel, which is why you'll see differences at the mosaic edges. @Goyo's suggestion is one possible solution; overlap the tiles enough to cover the interpolation neighbourhood.

Comment: Besides, you do not really want to resize a geotiff but resample it.

Comment: @Knulph You might want to check if gdalwarp can do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

As Goyo has already commented, you can use [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) to resample the image. If you are a Mac or Linux user, you can run gdalwarp directly from the command line:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -ts 20000 20000 -r cubic InputImage.tif OutputImage.tif
```

The -ts option allows you to specify the target size of the output raster (width, height).

gdalwarp has several resampling methods, but the cubic or bilinear algorithms are the most widely used within the remote sensing and GIS community.